# Different Colour above Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

i am creating project that have many activity. The first time i use navigation drawer as default activity. Then i create new basic activity inside it. i set my primary colour something like green. And the problem is i don't know why background colour at top different between the navigation drawer and basic activity. The drawer navigation has Green background but the Basic Activity its Grey background colour. i check my Android Manifest it have same App Theme No Action Bar. I want both have same(green) background colour.. Any suggest? Thank you

Drawer Navigation layout.
[image: this is drawer navigation layout look like in top action bar]

Basic Activity layout
[image: this is basic activity layout on action bar]

Comment: Really did not understand what problem you are facing pls explain

Answer (score 0):

Use secondary color somewhat dark green in `colors.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to onCreate of your activity. And add green color in colors.xml

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = activity.getWindow();
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.green));
            }
```